# Why is it that when I add yolk to vinegar and olive oil, it doesn't create a stratification?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Why is it that when I add yolk (which mostly consists of minerals, vitamins, lipids and proteins) to vinegar and olive oil, it doesn't create a stratification?

I'm really confused about this because if I only add vinegar to olive oil it actually does create a stratification. Could it be because the proteins somehow react with the fat in the olive oil or what's going on?

Comment: Please see “Mayonnaise” in wiki.

Comment: With the egg yolk and mechanical whipping, you're making a more stable emulsion than without the egg yolk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The egg yolk contains a lot of [lecithin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecithin), which is a phospholipid with 1 fatty acyl replaced with phosphatidylcholine.

It acts like emulsifier, what is used in industrial food production.